# Unable to insert degree symbol in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Using a PHP entry form when I insert the degree symbol instead saving it as it's diplayed the value in MySQL is `"Â°"`, for example if I write `"37°C"` it is saved as `"37Â°C"`

This is an example of my code

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="inc" placeholder="48 Hrs Aerobic, 37°C" value="48 Hrs Aerobic, 37°C">
```

The character is also shown as `"Â°C"` when the data is fetch from the DB.

Comment: Please post some code and explain what you tried, which errors you got etc.

Comment: Also, what encoding does the database table have?

Comment: <input class="form-control" type="text" name="inc" placeholder="48 Hrs Aerobic, 37°C" 
value="48 Hrs Aerobic, 37°C">

Comment: column data type is test and collation is latin1_general_ci

Comment: also used code **&#176;** but instead of **°** it insert ** Â°**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of the encoding format of your MySQL database. Please set it to one of the following and make sure your headers say UTF-8 too:

```
utf8_general_ci
utf8_unicode_ci
utf8mb4_general_ci
utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

*Go by the above order.*

And in your PHP, if needed:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

If everything else fails, convert `°` to `&deg;` and let the browser decide it.

Comment: but when I insert **&#176;C** to get output like °C, it insert it like Â°C

Comment: @user3244104 What's your DB encoding?

Comment: charset latin1 and collation latin1_swedish_ci

Comment: @user3244104 **I answered your question to change it to `utf8_general_ci
utf8_unicode_ci
utf8mb4_general_ci
utf8mb4_unicode_ci`!!!**

Comment: unable to change database collation or charset instead of I had changed same in table

Comment: Okay, if you put `&#176;` what does it output?

Comment: using **ALTER DATABASE diagnostic CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;** to change complete database charset and collation

Comment: @user3244104 What did it result in?

Comment: only **°** but I need to insert C also after °

Comment: tried same **&#176;C** but output is Â°C instead of °C

Comment: @user3244104 So you say, `&#176;` is `°` and `&#176;C` is `Â°C`?

Comment: Insert  &#176;C  with htmlentities

Comment: The best results are obtained by setting the database itself in UTF-8, (as shown in the answer), the database connection in UTF-8 (not shown) and the HTML in UTF-8 (shown in the answer).
Changing the connection to UTF-8 in an interactive connection is done by ````charset utf8;```` (mysql), depending on the language and methods used, you also need to do the same for automated connections. E.g.: in php-mysqli: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Answer (score -1):

In your php code do `utf8_decode($value)`.