# Utf8 issue with ° on mysql insert

Tags: mysql, laravel, utf8mb4

i have a project that running on Laravel.

My function get files ( UTF8 files ) in storage then parse/insert datas into mysql table ( Mysql is in utf8mb4_unicode_ci ) .

I'm stucked because of this error on some files on insert  : General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xC2'

Concerned insert text fail : "La clairière d'Eole n°5"

The issue seems to be the "°" charactere. When i remove it, the insert work. No problem with the accent, juste the ° and i dont know why.

I tried some preg_replace, iconv but without success.

Comment: Could you try with with utf8_general_ci for your database ?

Comment: i can insert `La clairière d'Eole n°5` without problem on `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` or `utf8mb4_bin` , and mysql default-character-set=utf8mb4

Comment: it work if i do an utf8_encode but the text become "Lotissement La clairiÃ¨re d'Eole nÂ 
°5 "

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the software you are using to read your CSV you may need to adjust the CSV document outputting script.

On Windows, MS Excel, expects an UTF-8 encoded CSV with its corresponding BOM character. To fullfill this requirement, you simply need to add the UTF-8 BOM character.

On a MacOS system, MS Excel requires a CSV encoded in UTF-16 LE using the tab character as delimiter.

You can use this library for parse csv file. They already include this stuff into library. https://csv.thephpleague.com/9.0/interoperability/encoding/

Comment: I see what you mean but i read flat text file with delimited position, no CSV here.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34480910/unable-to-insert-degree-symbol-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like somethings is set to ascii, not utf8, nor even latin1.

`°` is not available in ascii, hence the likely cause of the error.  In latin1, it is hex `B0`.  In utf8, it is `C2B0`.  Since there error message mentions only `C2` I am guessing the target character set is ascii, not latin1.

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the technique you are using for reading the files -- more than "read flat text file".